# Scala array splitting

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, split

For a given `Array[Byte]` such as

```
val in = Array(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 10)
```

how to split it by value `10` so that

```
val out = in.arr_split(10)
```

would deliver

```
Array( Array(104, 101, 108, 108, 111), 
       Array(119, 111, 114, 108, 100))
```

Assume in general many occurrences of splitting elements, for instance many `10`.

If possible, a parallel solution is desired.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Convert it to a string (it looks very like ascii values to me), and then use split to split it on new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
  def split(l: Array[Int], i:Int):Array[Array[Int]] = {
    l match {
      case Array() => Array()
      case _ =>
        val (h, t) = l.span(a => a != i)
        Array(h) ++ split(t.drop(1), i)
    }
  }

  val in = Array(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 10)

  val out = split(in, 10) 
// res: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(104, 101, 108, 108, 111), Array(119, 111, 114, 108, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

[scalaz-stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) solution. Instead of Array I use Vector here.

```
  val in = Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 10)
  val P = scalaz.stream.Process
  implicit val eq = scalaz.Equal.equal[Int]((l, r) => l == r)
  println(P.emitSeq[Task, Int](in).splitOn(10).filter(!_.isEmpty).runLog.run)
```

Output:

```
Vector(Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111), Vector(119, 111, 114, 108, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pimped version

```
  implicit def toDivide[A, B <% TraversableLike[A, B]](a : B) = new {
    private def divide(x : B, condition: (A) => Boolean) : Iterable[B] = {

      if (x.size > 0)
        x.span(condition) match {
          case (e, f) => if (e.size > 0) Iterable(e) ++ divide(f.drop(1),condition) else Iterable(f)
        }
      else
        Iterable()
    }
    def divide(condition: (A) => Boolean): Iterable[B] = divide(a, condition)
  }
```